Is this an equivalence of connectedness in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?
Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with the following property: for every $B\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$, $A\cap Bd(B)\neq \emptyset$ (i.e., $A$ has non-empty intersection with the boundary of $B$) whenever $A\cap B \neq \emptyset \neq A\cap (\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus B)$. Must $A$ be connected?
This is related to this question: Is this an equivalence of connectedness? As Moishe Kohan showed, the property above does not imply connectedness in arbitrary topological spaces. Now I am interested in which cases there is a positive answer and it seems to me that a good candidate is the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.
For example, $A$ is connected provided that $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Indeed, if this were not the case, then there would exist $x,y\in A$ and $z\in \mathbb{R}$ with $x<z<y$ and $z\not\in A$. Therefore, $B:= (-\infty,z)$ satisfies $x\in A\cap B$, $y\in A\cap (\mathbb{R}\setminus B)$ and $A \cap Bd(B) = \emptyset$. What happens in higher dimensions?

The right condition on your ambient topological space is Hausdorff completely normal or $T5$.

Yes. For a general topological space $X$, let us call a subset $A\subseteq X$ strongly disconnected if there exists open disjoint sets $U, V \subseteq X$ such that $A\cap U\neq \emptyset$, $A\cap V\neq \emptyset$ and $A\subseteq U \cup V$. Note that this is a stronger condition than being disconnected. However, I claim that your property is equivalent to not being strongly disconnected.
Indeed, if $A$ is strongly disconnected and $U$ and $V$ are as in the definition, then for the set $B:=U$ we have $A\cap B\neq \emptyset \neq A \cap (X\backslash B)$, but $\text{Bd}(B)=\overline{U}\backslash U$ does not intersect $A$. Then your condition is not satisfied. On the other hand, assuming your condition is not satisfied, pick a subset $B$ such that $A\cap B\neq \emptyset \neq A \cap (X\backslash B)$, but $A\cap \text{Bd}(B)=\emptyset$. Putting $U:=\text{Int}(B)$ and $V:=X\backslash \overline{B}$ we have $$A\cap U=A\cap B\neq \emptyset \neq A \cap (X\backslash B)=A\cap V$$ and $A\subseteq U \cup V$. Hence $A$ is strongly disconnected.
I claim that for metric spaces $(X,d)$ (in particular for $\mathbb{R}^n$) the notions of strongly disconnected and disconnected coincide. This will imply that subset of a metric space that satisfies your property has to be connected. Indeed, assume $A\subseteq X$ is disconnected and pick open subsets $U', V'\subseteq X$ such that $A\cap U'\neq \emptyset$, $A\cap V'\neq \emptyset$, $A\cap U'\cap V'=\emptyset$ and $A\subseteq U' \cup V'$. Consider the sets
$$U:=\{x\in X \mid d(x, A\cap U')<d(x, A\cap V')\},$$
$$V:=\{x\in X \mid d(x, A\cap U')>d(x, A\cap V')\}.$$
And voilà, $U$ and $V$ witness the strong disconnectedness condition.

Right. Or one can refer to an earlier answer about connected subsets of metric spaces here.

Interesting! Thank you very much for the answer.
